# Chrome and waiting image - jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I just wonder if anyone can fix/explain this

i have simple script like this, which is working fine

```
$(document).on("click", '#toexcel', function () {
    if (exp_sql) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "xtras/toExcel.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "sql=" + encodeURIComponent(exp_sql),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#wait").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#wait").hide();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                exp_sql = '';
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

my `wait` img implemented like:

```
<img src="css/wait.gif" id="wait" style="display: none;" />
```

My problem is that image never shows in Chrome on successful respond, despite if i need to wait few seconds before Excel download start.
but it shows if response is unsuccessful (problem with php script it calls) - why is that?

---

BTW

i tried to put `$("#wait").hide();` in `success` - makes no difference...

---

should i mention that this is internal domain website not hosted on internet?

Chrome version - Version 27.0.1453.110 m - and in Firefox it works correctly!

Comment: Your problem is that wait image not been shown or not be hidden? "but in Chrome it never show on success" as your code suggest, you want to hide it oncomplete, so i don't really understand

Comment: @roasted i want img to show while waiting to download excel. in Firefox it works as expected. but in Chrome it never shows, only if there is a problem with php script that it calls

Comment: Try showing the `img` before `$.ajax()` call, maybe your processing time is to small and the image can't be loaded before it gets hidden again. In such cases I usually show the image at all times and only change the opacity.

Comment: What if you force no cache: `url: "xtras/toExcel.php?"+$.now(),`  or `cache: false,` ?

Comment: @roasted yes i force no cache by - `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` - does that matter??

Comment: @slash197 - just tried that - didn't work (again - in Chrome)

Comment: @roasted - just tried that... not sure if it's coincident, but respond is much quicker now - no time for `wait` img!...

Comment: @roasted - thanks, tried that and img never showed

Comment: and if you remove all `$("#wait").hide();` , is image shown?

Comment: @roasted - good point! and NO it didn't show!

Comment: @roasted - it cant be the problem with the img - as i said, if php script has error and doesn't respond correctly to ajax back - img shows! - tried `beforeSend: function(){
      $("#wait").show();
      alert('here');
     },` - alert fires up!

Comment: what type of error? or what is the error produced from php file?

Comment: Ok, so i don't know where your problem comes from, sorry. If you have a public available link, maybe we could test it

Comment: @Kichu - i said it as an example. no errors on jquery

Comment: @roasted - unfortunately no... it's internal webserver, not available to public, but i'll try to produce it in jsfiddle

Comment: works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vKq3/

Comment: @roasted - yes it does.... would this be something to do that the server is on internal domain then?

Comment: The only problem with internal server i'm aware of could be if image comes with src prefixed with 'file://' but as you said if error from ajax, image is shown, so, i'm sorry, i cannot understand what is the problem here

Comment: ok, try this, without doing any click, just go into the Chrome debug console and type `$('#wait').show()`... if it does not show then there is no problem with the ajax thing but just with the image...

Comment: @Tallmaris - i typed - `$('#wait').show()` and respond was -
`[
<img src=​"css/​wait.gif" id=​"wait" style>
]`​ - but img didn't show

Comment: @Tallmaris no sorry - image DID show

Comment: ok... then the other thing I can think of is that the `#toexcel` element (or one of its parents) has some other events attached that are confusing chrome (or maybe it is a link?). Try changing the event function to stop the event before the ajax call: `.on("click", '#toexcel', function (evt) { evt.stopPropagation(); evt.preventDefault(); ...}`

Comment: @Tallmaris - no it hasn't got any html or java script... only `$response = array(
  'success' => true,
  'sql' => $sql,
  'url' => "PHPExcel/reports/$fname"
 );
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response);`but i will try ur suggestion

Comment: @Tallmaris - nothing changed... no image... i don't understand! in Firefox everything works as expected! (i don't use IE at all, so don't know...)

Comment: Maybe put the HTML around the element in the question? so we can see the `#toexcel` element and try to replicate it here. I have tried something simlar in Chrome and it works ok...

Comment: @Tallmaris sorry i dont understand what you mean about putting html around the code? do you mean providing full code of the page in question? well it's a lot for here... do you want to chat instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31654/discussion-between-tallmaris-and-elen)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(document).on("click", '#toexcel', function () {
    if (exp_sql) {
        $("#wait").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "xtras/toExcel.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "sql=" + encodeURIComponent(exp_sql),
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#wait").hide();
                exp_sql = '';
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        });
    };
});
```